# kill-ring-save rectangle and paste transposed?

Tags: copy-paste, yank, rectangle

Suppose I have some code written like:

```
a_to_b = self.tversky(a, b)
b_to_c = self.tversky(b, c)
d_to_e = self.tversky(d, e)
e_to_f = self.tversky(e, f)
g_to_h = self.tversky(g, h)
```

I would like to select as a rectangle the variable names `x_to_y` and then paste it into array as so:

```
return [a_to_b, b_to_c, d_to_e, e_to_f, g_to_h]
```

I don't necessarily need the commas in one command, but basically selecting a few columns and then applying `M-S ^` to each line. So I can get them all next to each other.

Comment: What is `M-S ^`,  and what did you intend by applying it to each line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select the rectangle (e.g. use `C-x SPC`).
2. Use this command (`M-x foo`) to copy the variables to the `kill-ring`, as the string `"a_to_b, b_to_c, d_to_e, e_to_f, g_to_h"`:

```lisp
(defun foo (beg end)
  (interactive "r")
  (let ((vars  (mapconcat #'identity
                          (extract-rectangle (region-beginning) (region-end))
                          ", ")))
    (kill-new vars)))
```

3. Move to where you want the result.
4. Use this command (`M-x bar`) to insert the result at point.

```lisp
(defun bar ()
  (interactive)
  (insert "return [")
  (yank)
  (insert "]\n"))
```

Comment: Thanks, `M-S ^` is `delete-indentation`. When I posted the question, I had an OS shortcut overiding that command and couldn't `C-h k` for it.

Comment: Hi @dylanjm, that would normally be written `M-^` (or `S-M-6`, but that ties you to a US or UK keyboard).